# Controller not seen

Tags: scala, playframework

I have created a Scala project and I added the following controller in `/app/controllers`:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

class Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }

}
```

I have added its `index` method to the routes file:

```
GET      /                          controllers.Application.index
```

However, when I access `localhost:9000` in the browser, I get the error:

```
type Application is not a member of package controllers
```

Why is the controller not visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because your route refers to a *static* controller, i.e. an `object` rather than a class. There are a few different ways you could fix this:

Declare your controller as an object:

```
object Application extends Controller {
    ...
}
```

Alternately, you can prefix the routes action reference with a `@`, indicating that it's a class that should be instantiated when the route is invoked:

```
GET      /                   @controllers.Application.index
```

You can also use the *injected*, rather than the (default) static router, which involves adding the following line to your `build.sbt`:

```
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

In the early versions of Play 2.0 controllers were always static objects, but in recent versions it is typical to use a class, into which you can inject components. Have a look at the [routes documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaRouting) for details.